# Condition in Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis, the proof for Rouché's theorem states, that if $|f(z))>|g(z))$ then $f_{t}$ has no zeroes on C, below:
[image: page1]

1. Why is it true that $f_{t}$ has no zeroes **on the circle** if $|f(z))>|g(z))$  . Both are holomorphic over C and its interior, implying they have no zeroes or poles on the interior or on the circle. Specifically, why is true on the circle and not on the interior?
2. If I assume, there are poles and zeroes in the interior, applying the argument principle to it, what happens to the number of poles, because he counts $n_{t}$ to be equal to the number of zeroes only.

I am a bit lost.

Comment: Gerard de Nerval takes his lobster, Tibault, for a walk (on a leash of course).   In the course of this walk, he circles a tree several times.  If the the leash is shorter than the distance Nerval ever gets to the tree, then the lobster circles the tree the same number of times as Nerval.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Because

$$0=f_t(z)=f(z)+tg(z)\implies |f(z)|=|-tg(z)|=t|g(z)\le|g(z)| ...\text{contradiction!}$$

2.- There are no poles since $\;f_t\neq0\;$ ...

Comment: Should'nt what you stated be true or all of C(both on the circle and in the interior), since this condition is true for $z \in C$, so there can be no zeroes in the interior either. @ Plus both are holomorphic over all of C(on the boundary and interior) - so can I not conclude they have no zeroes or poles?  @DonAntonio

Comment: Or since $|f(z) > |f(z)|$ does this imply only the boundary? @DonAntonio

Comment: @curious_analyst I'm not sure I understand your questions: if $\;f(z)=-tg(z)\;$ we have a straightforward contradiction, as far as I see. I changed now the $\;<\;$ sign for $\;\le\;$ , to account for $\;t=1\;$ ...but it's just the same: whether $\;|f(z)|=|tg(z)|= \;or\;\le |g(z)\;$ , we get a contradiction...on $\;C\;$ , of course..

Comment: The contradiction solves the originally posed question, but my follow-up question is about whether its true only on the boundary of C not its interior? (because we are considering the modulus.) @DonAntonio.